# To buttonhole someone

Tags: idioms

Can you help me find a synonym to this  expression meaning to approach someone as if by grasping the person's garment to have his attention.

Could it be used informally to describe boys' attitude to get girls' attention?

Comment: I think your understanding of it is correct. Grabbing them by the lapels is the other form of that expression I've always understood.  I probably would say that women traditionally don't have button holes in their lapels, so perhaps not applicable in that direction.

Comment: I've never heard it used in the context of 'boys and girls'. It is heard more often in business life, when it is necessary to grasp someone's attention. 'We badly need to know the Chairman's views on the matter, see if you can buttonhole him at tonight's gathering'.

Comment: To *bend one's ear* is a similar idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually used in connection with someone with the proverbial bee in the bonnet, or someone with particularly urgent business. "I was buttonholed by a bible-thumper in the street". "She buttonholed him outside his office and demanded a decision". You wouldn't use it to describe a boy trying to get a girl's attention. You might say, "he came on to her" or "he got alongside her" or (in the north of England) "he tried to get his feet under the table".